# Randomize Laravel table rows to be unique

Tags: php, laravel, loops, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have an app that has Categories, Boards, and Pins. A category has many boards and has many pins. When I make a pin I assign it a category and I display it in a table which represents a board. A pin with the category "Code" will display on all the boards in the "Code" category. I need to randomize the order of each table row and it needs to be unique from all the other rows of that number. In other words, Boards "a", "b", and "c" contain pins "1", "2", and "3". Row 1 of board "a" can't contain the same pin as row 1 of boards "b" or "c".

I was thinking it would probably take some sort of a loop to check whether or not the rows contain the same data, though I am fairly new to Laravel and php, I don't really know how to set this up!

If I haven't been very clear or you need me to share some code jut let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Explode it to couple queries. first get random list for main board, process it, and for next board get data without it (`AND id NOT IN(list_id_from_prevous_queries)`)

Comment: ok though I don't really have a main board because they are being displayed with a foreach loop